# Prometheus metric Kube_pod_created retunr wrong date

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring

Im using kube_pod_created to get pod created time but it gives wrong Unix timestamp date
[image]

how can I fix this  ?
btw time() query retun date but delayed by an hour  can this cauz the problem ?  I changed my windows time so it match promethues but still same thing

Comment: I found out that the **sum by** is causing the problem I was using it just to make the result just display pod name is there any other way to do this ?